# Solidity web3 JS fix byPass hack?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I have some doups about how control de msg.sender using web3.

For example I have this function in solidity:
Where owner is the msg.sender used in costructor. for example is 0x9;

```
function NoPass() external view returns(string memory){
  require(msg.sender == owner, "NO ERES EL PROPIETARIO");
  return "HACKEADO";}
```

Then from JS I call this function like:

```
contract.methods.NoPass().call({from:"0x9"}).then(res=>{
     console.log(res);})
```

I can call this function and skip require because my call FROM i write the same account like owner.
How Can i fix it?
Because I save the account in a value then hacker can modifie this account value and skip requires.

In Send functions wrks
its just call functions
but meh it is normal?

Answer (score 0):

call() functions reads blockchain state and does not change state of blockchain. send() creates transaction and can change blockchain state. Access control is usually implemented only in functions which can change blockchain state. Also it would be good to use [OpenZeppelin Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-docs/blob/master/demo-docs/learn-about-access-control.md) for access control.

Comment: But if I wanna have a private value that only wanna check when I'm the owner...
I can't¿

Comment: Everything we put on the blockchain is visible to everyone publicly. The only options are Encrypt or Hash the sensitive data. We can encrypt our data and put the secret key secured somewhere off-chain. We can simply hash the secret key and put the hash on the blockchain.